# How do the cliclick and MouseTools command line tools differ?

Tags: macos, applications, applescript, command-line

I would like to perform double-clicks via AppleScript.

Two tools that I understand are suitable for the job (since AppleScript contains no built-in mechanism to do this) are [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) and [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html).

These two tools are very similar, sharing many features. Do they differ? Is one more reliable than the other?

Comment: MouseTools link is broken, so I tried cliclick -- it's incredibly easy to install and use from Terminal. Really impressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cliclicl is the easiest one to automate your work.
However too simple.
for example, In your terminal cliclicl dc:. will do double click.

I recommend using cliclicl If your purpose is just double click.
Mouse tools is relatively complex.

Try cliclicl.
If you need more powerful tool for automate, then use Mousetools.

Comment: I recomend to use cliclick with automator.
cliclick is easy to copy and paste.

Comment: I have used both. Current implementations with MouseTools. I have encountered some issues: the left single clicks sometimes do not register in MouseTools. So, I tend to use them both. But just like Sonicmario mentioned. clicclick is very straightforward.