# Watch Me Do or other method for exact pixel coordinate of mouse click (Automator)

Tags: automator

Is it possible to specify how a mouse click point is recorded or processed in Watch Me Do?

had thought it was exact pixel position recorded but it seems that in a safari browser it is relative to the page scroll...

Is there another way to simulate actions clicking in exact locations (irrespectivec of browser scrollbar)?

Specifically, I would prefer a non-third party tool solution - using Automator if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Automator can ‘Run AppleScript’, and you can click at a coordinate using AppleScript:

> ```
> tell application "System Events"
>   click at {123,456}
> end tell
> ```

[How do I make the mouse click at current location using AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/266784/37797)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the automator Watch Me Do clicks to the AppleScript absolute clicks?

Comment: Rather, how would you get the applescript click coordinates?

Comment: @ina I rely on the good old try and miss.

Comment: Here's a trick to quickly find the absolute coordinates of any pixel on the screen: Press `⌘ + Shift + 4` to start a screenshot. Drag from the top, left corner of the screen to the desired point. The coordinates are displayed on the bottom right corner of the bounding square. Hit Escape to cancel the screenshot once you have the coordinates.