# Trying to create apple script to press one of two buttons on a safari screen

Tags: applescript, safari

There are two buttons on a safari screen that read "confirm" and "deny" that I would like to be able to press.  When I inspect elements, the code for the two buttons are:

= $0

Can someone suggest how I get AppleScript to do this - if I just want to press 'deny'?  The one other time I got AppleScript to press a button, there was only one button on the screen and I used a javascript command that just involved ".submit" which wouldn't differentiate the two buttons here.

Also, I know mousetools can be used if the button always appears in the exact same place but (a) it does not appear in the exact same place and (b) I can't download mousetools anymore - the links to it are dead.

thank you!

Comment: Same question as before - is the button always in the same place? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266784/how-do-i-make-the-mouse-click-at-current-location-using-applescript